# Android Dev: Something wrong with my function, but I've been stuck for two hours

Tags: java, android, adt, preferences, shared

so I am making my 2nd app, and I decided to build a menu which has multiple skins/icon sets and can randomize main menu buttons, I got everything working, then I started developing Introduction screen which is launched when user first launches app using Dialog boxes, now I got colors changing dynamically when user selects different scheme, which works fine, and when user comes to box which asks if they want to randomize colors of menu buttons every time:

If I click on Randomize it does change dynamically, but if I tick sequential then it doesn't change at all, I don't get it.

I have 3 main files:
ConversePrefs.java, I won't post it as I am 100% sure it's correct as it's just a set of shortcut functions for getting shared preferences.

MainMenu.java - main activity/main menu:

```
package com.arl.conversion;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {
    private static final OnClickListener PreSetupsColor = null;
    final Context context = this;
    ColorCollections cc = new ColorCollections(context);

    List<String> colorList = null;
    int currentIndex = 0;

    public void LoadColorPalette(){
        ConversePrefs cp = new ConversePrefs(this);
        colorList = cc.GetColorList(cp.GetIntSetting("UsersColor", 0),cp.GetBolSetting("UsersRandomizer", false));
    }

    public void SetBtnColour(int btn){  
        Button bttn = (Button)findViewById(btn);
        bttn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorList.get(currentIndex))); 
        currentIndex++;
    }

    public void GenerateButtonsDefault(){
        ConversePrefs cp = new ConversePrefs(this);
        LoadColorPalette();
        SetBtnColour(R.id.DistanceBtn);
        SetBtnColour(R.id.VolumeBtn);
        SetBtnColour(R.id.AreaBtn);
        SetBtnColour(R.id.ClothingBtn);
        SetBtnColour(R.id.ElectricBtn);
        SetBtnColour(R.id.TempBtn);
        SetBtnColour(R.id.TimeBtn);
        SetBtnColour(R.id.MoneyBtn);
        SetBtnColour(R.id.SpeedBtn);
        SetBtnColour(R.id.MathBtn);
        SetBtnColour(R.id.CurrencyBtn);
        SetBtnColour(R.id.OptionsBtn);
    }

    public void RefreshMenu(){
        currentIndex = 0;
        GenerateButtonsDefault();
    }



//SECOND
    public void PreSetuposColor(final View v){
        final ConversePrefs cp = new ConversePrefs(this);
        String[] ColorSchemes = {"Windows 8", "Modern Urban"};
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
        setTitle("Color Scheme").
        setSingleChoiceItems(ColorSchemes, cp.GetIntSetting("UsersColor", 0), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                cp.SetIntSetting("UsersColor", which);
                RefreshMenu();
            }
        }).
        setPositiveButton("Continue", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                MainMenu.this.PreSetupRandoms(v);

            }
        }).setNeutralButton("Back", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                MainMenu.this.PreSetupsWelcome(v);

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Quit", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                System.exit(0);

            }
        }).setCancelable(false).show();
    }
// THIRD
    public void PreSetupRandoms(final View v){
        final ConversePrefs cp = new ConversePrefs(this);
        String[] FalseAndTrue = {"Sequential", "Randomize"};
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
        setTitle("Randomize Colors?").
        setSingleChoiceItems(FalseAndTrue, cp.GetBoolInt(cp.GetBolSetting("UsersRandomizer", false)), new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                cp.SetBooleanSetting("UsersRandomizer", cp.GetIntBool(which));
                RefreshMenu();
            }
        }).setPositiveButton("Continue", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO

            }
        }).setNeutralButton("Back", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                MainMenu.this.PreSetuposColor(v);

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Quit", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                System.exit(0);

            }
        }).setCancelable(false).show();
    }
//FIRST
    public void PreSetupsWelcome(final View v){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
        setTitle("Welcome").
        setMessage("It seems that this is the first time application was ran on this device, you will be now presented with app appearance setup of your own choice.").
        setPositiveButton("Continue", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                MainMenu.this.PreSetuposColor(v);

            }
        }).
        setNegativeButton("Quit", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }).
        setCancelable(false).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ConversePrefs cp = new ConversePrefs(this);
        //LoadColorPalette();
        setContentView(cc.GetTheme(cp.GetIntSetting("ThemeName", 0)));
        GenerateButtonsDefault();
        PreSetupsWelcome(new View(this));

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

ColorCollections.java - file that has info about colors/and few functions for retrieval.

```
package com.arl.conversion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;

public class ColorCollections{
     Context context;
     public ColorCollections(Context context){
            this.context = context;
        }
    //Color Palettes.
    public static String[] Win8 = new String[]{"#008299","#00A0B1","#2672EC","#2E8DEF","#8C0095","#A700AE","#5133AB","#643EBF","#AC193D","#BF1E4B","#D24726","#DC572E","#008A00","#00A600","#094AB2","#0A5BC4"};
    public static String[] ModernUrban = new String[]{"#47B6BE","#73CC3E","#FF7149","#FF5063","#FF6999","#233977","#4B9364","#8A8F1D","#A63B52","#B23265","#883E57","#888788","#87A087"};

    public List<String> GetColorList(int colorindex, boolean randomizer){
        List<String> colorList = Arrays.asList(Win8);
        switch(colorindex){
        case 0:
            colorList = Arrays.asList(Win8);
            break;
        case 1:
            colorList = Arrays.asList(ModernUrban);
            break;
        }

        if(randomizer == true){
            Collections.shuffle(colorList);
            Collections.shuffle(colorList);
            Collections.shuffle(colorList);
            Collections.shuffle(colorList);
        }
        return colorList;
    }
    public int GetTheme(int theme){
        int themeID = 0;
        switch(theme){
        case 0:
            themeID = R.layout.activity_main_menu_light;
            break;
        case 1:
            themeID = R.layout.activity_main_menu_light_bg;
            break;
        case 2:
            themeID = R.layout.activity_main_menu_dark;
            break;
        case 3:
            themeID = R.layout.activity_main_menu_dark_bg;
            break;
        }       
        return themeID;
    }

}
```

Can somebody please identify problem? I've been stuck with this for past 2 hours, and tried out everything, even ended up having so much more efficient code (I know it may look bad to you, but it was worse, trust me).

Also I have 4 sets of icons, 12 icons in each set, each set has prefix for icon, it's an actual imported drawable .png. is there any better way to create XML list of them than manually type?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the exact location of the problem, but it would be beneficial for you to do debugging if you haven't, and step into the function that is setSingleChoiceItems(...) as a start. You can use a ListView to display a XML list. Here is an example generated from a strings.xml file: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/ . More complicated ListViews will require you to create a custom adapter class.

Comment: Is there anything you think could be causing it?

Comment: when you select 'sequential', are you correctly setting the layout scheme like 'random' is? on another note, I wouldn't fret too much over a problem like this on a learning app. you will quickly develop the skills to the future to solve this issue :)